# Referenced previous command's output

Tags: 11.10, command-line

Suppose you are in following situation:

```
<command 1>
<output of command 1>
<want to use output of command 1 here without have to retype it>
```

My specific case:

```
which eclipse
/usr/bin/eclipse
ldd /usr/bin/eclipe
```

But I would prefer not to have to type this last line out, is there any shortcut?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `$()`:

```
ldd "$(which eclipse)"
```

Comment: Or backticks: `ldd \`which eclipse\``

Comment: @Blair: `$()` is preferred over backticks, because it's nestable. Thus, it's good to form the habit of using `$()`, even when they aren't strictly necessary.

Comment: @ScottSeverance: Thanks, I'd never considered that. I'll have to try and change my habits :).